# Unable to delete and display confirm box

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, confirm

I am unable to delete or display a confirm box in Rails 3.1.

I have the following lines in my `application.hmtl.erb` layout :

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag  "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

I have also tried to change "application" to `:defaults` or "prototype" or "jquery" but it didn't change anything.

Need help with this !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirm boxes and routing to REST actions are done by the the unobtrusive javascript file. You have this problem, because you don't have it included.

Check inside your `application.js` if you have the following lines (before any actual javascript code):

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

This example assumes that you have the `jquery-rails` gem in your `Gemfile`. If you have `prototype-rails`, you should switch to:

```
//= require prototype
//= require prototype_ujs
```

Comment: I realized that I did not have the jquery-rails gem installed properly. I installed it and added the lines. Thanks for the answer! :)